# Can't make first div shown after checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I'm having trouble making the first div below the checkbox hide, when checkbox is checked.
Basically, the script works, it hides the divs, but not the very first below the checkbox. Is there a function from jQ that manages this type of actions?

My script contains:

```
$("div[class=content]").hide();
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            $(this).siblings().show();
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).siblings().hide();
        }
    });
```

And the HTML part:

```
<form action="" method="post" style="border:1; border-style:solid;">
    <input name="checkbox" id="table" type=checkbox /> a TABLE<br />
        <div class=content id="table">
            COLs <input type=text name=COLs /><br />
            ROWs <input type=text name=ROWs /><br />
            <input type=submit name=submit_table value="create table" />
        </div>
    <br/>
    <br />
    <input name="checkbox" id="image" type=checkbox /> an IMAGE<br />
        <div class=content id="image">
            Width <input type=text name=Width /><br />
            Height <input type=text name=Height /><br />
            <input type=submit name=submit_image value="see image" />
        </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input name="checkbox" id="text" type=checkbox /> some TEXT<br />
        <div class=content id="text">
            <input type=text name=text_string /><br />
            Color <input type=text name=Color /><br />
            Size <input type=text name=Size /><br />
            <input type=checkbox name=text_font value=bold /><strong>bold</strong> <input type=checkbox name=text_font value=italic /><i>italic</i> <input type=checkbox name=text_font value=underline /><u>underline</u><br />
            <input type=submit name=submit_text value="post text" />
        </div>
    <br />

    <input name="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

So, what should if do? When the checkbox from "a TABLE" is checked, the div[id=table] should be visible, when the checkbox from "an image" is checked, the div[id=image] should be visible ... but automatically.

Let's say that I have a thousand checkboxex with some sort of content for each one to be shown when checked. I defenitely don't want to make an :if: for each one; but get the FIRST DIV BELOW the clicked checkbox.

Hopefully I was clear enough. So please, could you help?

PS: I also want those divs hidden when first loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("div[class=content]").hide();
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            $(this).siblings(".content").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).siblings(".content").hide();
        }
    });
```

You may also want to make sure you are surrounding your html attribute values with quotes (I noticed your div's class value has no quotes around it.

Wrap your input and divs in a parent div so not all of the other inputs/divs will be siblings.

```
<form action="" method="post" style="border:1; border-style:solid;">
    <div>
        <input name="checkbox" id="table" type=checkbox /> a TABLE<br />
        <div class=content id="table">
            COLs <input type=text name=COLs /><br />
            ROWs <input type=text name=ROWs /><br />
            <input type=submit name=submit_table value="create table" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br />
    <div>
        <input name="checkbox" id="image" type=checkbox /> an IMAGE<br />
        <div class=content id="image">
            Width <input type=text name=Width /><br />
            Height <input type=text name=Height /><br />
            <input type=submit name=submit_image value="see image" />
        </div>
     </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div>
        <input name="checkbox" id="text" type=checkbox /> some TEXT<br />
        <div class=content id="text">
            <input type=text name=text_string /><br />
            Color <input type=text name=Color /><br />
            Size <input type=text name=Size /><br />
            <input type=checkbox name=text_font value=bold /><strong>bold</strong> <input type=checkbox name=text_font value=italic /><i>italic</i> <input type=checkbox name=text_font value=underline /><u>underline</u><br />
            <input type=submit name=submit_text value="post text" />
        </div>
     </div>
    <br />

    <input name="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! It still doesn't work. When a checkbox is checked, all the divs are shown... and I don't want it like that. Having no quotes to the attributes should be a probles unless the value given contains spaces, symbols or something like that.

Comment: I think I see the issue, all of those divs are actually siblings of the checkboxes based on your structure.  You could wrap each input and div in a parent div and then it would work

Answer (score 0):

***NOTE:*** your HTML markup is invalid, IDs must be unique on `document` context

You could use:

```
$("div[class=content]").hide(); // you should hide by default in CSS instead
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
    $(this).nextAll('.content').first().toggle(this.checked); // this.checked could be ommited here
});
```

### DEMO

Comment: It works just perfect! WOW! Thank you, sir! This being the 4th day trying to make this sort of simple things work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write:

```
$("div.content")
// or even
$(".content")
// insted of
$("div[class=content]")
// and
$(":checkbox")
// instead of
$("input[type=checkbox]")
// Could there be enything other than "input"?
```